# WPF WebBrowser throws a error in LoadCompleted module

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, browser

I have a WPF application that embeds a WebBrowser control.
The application is built with C# 4.0 and VS2010, and .NET 4.0

Sometimes, when I do a webBrowser.Navigate(Url) I get the error:

'System.DBNull' does not contain a definition for 'InnerHtml'

in my webBrowser_LoadCompleted event module.  The page loads, and it looks o.k.

My code looks like:

```
private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
  string htmlText;
  try {
    dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
    htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Charles

Comment: try to cast document to IHTMLDocument3 and then get documentElement.InnerHtml

Comment: @CBrauer:try using `doc.documentElement.OuterHtml;` instead `doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and casting to IHTMLDocument3 did the job. Before that I check if there actually is a loaded doc as this also was a problem for me:

```
dynamic doc = browser.Document;
string htmlText = "";
    if (doc != null)
        htmlText = ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)doc).documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi it might be a late reply. But I just come across this question. I was able to solve my problem by simply making the thread sleep for a while before getting the 'innerHTML'. I know its very unusual but it works.

So your code become

```
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
Thread.Sleep(100);
htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
```